# Drop down arrow img in firefox

Tags: firefox, drop-down-menu

I have tried to change the default arrow in drop down.

By adding this in css,

`background-image:url("downArrow.jpg") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;`

but the default arrow of drop down is not get replace in firefox, but in chrome its coming correctly.

How to fix this in firefox. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`<SELECT>` elements are not rendered by HTML, they're rendered by the browser/OS and styling them is quite limited. You cannot replace the arrow. All you can do is place an element on top of it and use script to fire the click as if it were part of the real drop-down.